# Appropriate time to email manager for interview followup

Tags: interviewing, job-search, follow-up

I had two interviews last week with different managers on Wednesday and Thursday. Each time the manager informed me when the following interview would be. So manager #1 set up the call with manager #2 immediately after the interview on Wednesday. Manager #2 informed me that I would have my final interview with the director sometime this week.

It's only Monday morning so it's a little early to reach out asking when this is likely to be scheduled. The problem is that I'm not sure who's going to be setting up the call (manager #2 or the executive assistant).

What would be the appropriate time to email manager #2 to ask for a timeline without sounding pushy? It would help me to be able to schedule my week around this final interview, but I'm aware that the director's schedule is likely packed.
Any help on the protocol here would be helpful.

Comment: Care perhaps sharing your location, to also consider possible locale-specific considerations?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I properly follow-up with a hiring manager, to check on the status of a position?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/how-do-i-properly-follow-up-with-a-hiring-manager-to-check-on-the-status-of-a-p)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What would be the appropriate time to email manager #2 to ask for a timeline without sounding pushy?

If you don't want to seem pushy you should wait for them to contact you. If they had this information they probably would have already contacted you. So for them to get it they would probably need to bug the Director above and beyond the initial request, which they may have to do as part of their role, but won't want to do just for your scheduling.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In the event that the interview isn't scheduled this week, would it be appropriate to contact manager#2 around Thursday/Friday asking if it's likely to be scheduled next week? Or should I do this next Monday– something like 'I haven't heard back about this since our chat, could I have a timeline on the interview schedule?'

Comment: up to you, I'd do it after the weekend, Tuesday perhaps. Often people don't want to start anything just before a weekend and it may be dealt with Monday.